# How can I apply a meta query for a single custom post type in the main query?

Tags: query, meta-query

I have custom post type called `event`, which has custom fields for `start_date` and `end_date`. For the event archive, I'm filtering out "expired" events using the following meta query added to the main query inside a `pre_get_posts` filter, which works fine:

```
if ( is_post_type_archive( 'event' ) ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'start_date',
            'value' => $today = date( 'Ymd' ),
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'end_date',
            'value' => $today = date( 'Ymd' ),
            'compare' => '>='
        ),
    ) );
}
```

I'd like to do the same for search queries. Is it possible to add a meta query to the main query and have it only apply to a certain post type (i.e. `event`)? Pseudocode (I know this doesn't work, but to illustrate):

```
if ( is_search() ) {
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'post_type',
            'value' => 'event',
            'compare' => '!=',
        ),
        array(
            ....
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case that the `start_date` custom field only exists for the `event` post type, this works:

```
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'start_date',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'start_date',
        'value' => $today = date( 'Ymd' ),
        'compare' => '>=',
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'end_date',
        'value' => $today = date( 'Ymd' ),
        'compare' => '>=',
    ),
) );
```

By comparing the `start_date` key to `NOT EXISTS`, the other post types are not filtered out. Obviously this is not an ideal solution, so I'm still curious if there are better ideas out there.

Comment: This is pretty much as much as you can do with what Wordpress has to offer. This is exactly what I had in mind, just did not have time to put it into code. The only other way I see of doing this is with a custom SQL query which can get quite messy, and you loose all your filters as well.

Comment: Allright, thanks for the comment @PieterGoosen. Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

Your given answer is pretty smart!!

Another way I think you could accomplish the same thing and be a little bit more specific would be to pick a new key that exists only on the second post type and compare with EXISTS.

So your second post type is `search` (not exactly sure from your example). Your first post type is `event`. If your main query is searching through both post types, then this meta_query would include all posts of the second post type.

```
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'my_exclusive_meta_key_for_my_other_post_type',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ),
    ...
) );
```